# Escape sequence issue - Batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to send an e-mail using PowerShell commands in a batch file. To do this, I implemented a function called **sendMail**. I'm calling it like this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call:sendMail
powershell -command "!_mailCommand!"
endlocal
pause&goto:eof
```

And my **sendMail** function:

```
:sendMail

set "_mailCommand=&{$filenameAndPath = '!resultFile!';"
set "_mailCommand=%_mailCommand%$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage('%_mailFrom%', '%_mailTo%', '%_mailSubject%', '%_mailBody%');"
set "_mailCommand=%_mailCommand%$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath);"
set "_mailCommand=%_mailCommand%$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment);"
set "_mailCommand=%_mailCommand%$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient('%_mailHost%', %_mailPort%);"
set "_mailCommand=%_mailCommand%$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true;"
set "_mailCommand=%_mailCommand%$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential('%_mailFrom%','%_mailSenderPassword%');"
set "_mailCommand=%_mailCommand%$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)}"
echo %_mailSenderPassword%
```

Unexpectedly I get an output like this:

> 12345Aa!
>
> Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
>
> At line:1 char:499
>   ... m','12345Aa^');$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)}
>
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

As you can guess, my password is *12345Aa!* and I defined it at the beginning of my code as `set "_mailSenderPassword=12345Aa^^!"`

So what am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `set "_mailSenderPassword=12345Aa^!"` instead

Comment: Why do't you use a builtin `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet?

Comment: I would have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288552/how-can-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark-in-cmd-scripts. While in some casees `^^!` is the escape for `!` I am not seeing that interpeted properly. Specifically this response http://stackoverflow.com/a/11228791/3829407 for use that has variable expansion. `!_mailSenderPassword!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using delayed expansion, then you should avoid percent expansion, else you get problems with carets`^` and exclamation marks`!` and sometimes also with quotes.

As after the percent expansion the content will be parsed for special characters, but after delayed expansion it will be used unchanged.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_mailSenderPassword=12345Aa^!"
call :sendMail
powershell -command "!_mailCommand!"
exit /b

:sendMail
set "_mailCommand=&{$filenameAndPath = '!resultFile!';"
set "_mailCommand=!_mailCommand!$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage('!_mailFrom!', '!_mailTo!', '!_mailSubject!', '!_mailBody!');"
set "_mailCommand=!_mailCommand!$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath);"
set "_mailCommand=!_mailCommand!$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment);"
set "_mailCommand=!_mailCommand!$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient('!_mailHost!', !_mailPort!);"
set "_mailCommand=!_mailCommand!$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true;"
set "_mailCommand=!_mailCommand!$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential('!_mailFrom!','!_mailSenderPassword!');"
set "_mailCommand=!_mailCommand!$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)}"
echo !_mailSenderPassword!
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

The following simplified example worked for me (it successfully echoed `12345Aa^!`):

```
set "_mailSenderPassword=12345Aa^!"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call:sendMail
powershell -command "!_mailCommand!"
endlocal
pause&goto:eof

:sendMail
set "_mailCommand=echo '%_mailSenderPassword%';"
echo %_mailSenderPassword%
echo %_mailCommand%
```

Note that I had to set `_mailSenderPassword` *before* I call `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Also there's one funny quirk: you still *can* get the same result while under `enabledelayedexpansion`, but you have to use 3 (*three*) caret characters. E.g. the following will work:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_mailSenderPassword=12345Aa^^^!"

call:sendMail
powershell -command "!_mailCommand!"
endlocal
pause&goto:eof

:sendMail
set "_mailCommand=echo '%_mailSenderPassword%';"
echo %_mailSenderPassword%
echo %_mailCommand%
```