# How to escape ! in a variable's value?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

How may I escape embedded ! characters in the value of a variable PL used in delayed expansion !PL!, such that they are not interpreted as delimiters?

E.g. to remedy the failure of this when %%P contains ! .

```
FOR %%P IN (%input%\*.M3U) DO (
    echo Processing playlist "%%P"

    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN ('type "%%P"') DO (
      SET PL=%%~pP%%L
      echo  Processing reference "!PL!"
    )
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

EDIT: Paul's limited-applicability workaround:

```
FOR %%P IN (%input%\*.M3U) DO (
    echo Processing playlist "%%P"

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN ('type "%%P"') DO (
      SET PL=%%~pP%%L
      SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
      echo  Processing reference "!PL!"
      ENDLOCAL
    )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I escape an exclamation mark ! in cmd scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288552/how-can-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark-in-cmd-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can search/replace a `!` inside a `!var!` (*`!myvar:^^!=!!` doesn't work*) but you can display `!` in var like:

```
@echo off
(
echo !!myfolder
echo myfi!es
echo !234
)>sample.txt
for /f %%a in (sample.txt) do (
  set "myvar=%%a"
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  echo !myvar!
  endlocal
)
```

You can transpose on your code like this:

```
for %%p in (%input%\*.m3u) do (
    echo processing playlist "%%p"

    for /f "tokens=*" %%l in ('type "%%p"') do (
      set pl=%%~pp%%l
      setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
      echo  processing reference "!pl!"
      endlocal
    )
)
```

Comment: You can replace it only with percent expansion. `echo %myvar:!=someThingElse%`

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the transpose workaround. Works fine. Still it would be useful to have a full solution. And thanks for the block redirect technique, which will hopefully improve my future SO CMD questions :)